# Adding a computed column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, calculated-columns

I'm trying to add a column called 'price' to my order_details table. I want it to calculate the price from different prices of products from other tables.

```
alter table order_detail add column Price decimal(5,2) as 

(CASE (order_detail.item_id, 
       item.item_id, 
       bagel.item_id, 
       bagelfilling.item_id, 
       Item.price, 
       bagelfilling.price,
       order_detail.quantity,
       order_detail.discount,
       drink_sizes.price,
       drink.item_id)

        WHEN (order_detail.item_id = item.item_id) AND (item.item_ID = bagel.item_id) AND (bagel.item_id = bagelfilling.item_id)
            THEN ((Item.price + bagelfilling.price)*order_detail.quantity)-order_detail.discount


        WHEN (order_detail.item_id = item.item_id) AND (item.item_ID = drink.item_id)
            THEN ((Item.price + drink_sizes.price)*order_detail.quantity)-order_detail.discount

        WHEN (order_detail.item_id = item.item_id) AND (item.item_ID = bagel.item_id)  
            THEN (Item.price*order_detail.quantity)-order_detail.discount

        WHEN (order_detail.item_id = item.item_id) AND (item.item_ID = drink.item_id)
            THEN (Item.price*order_detail.quantity)-order_detail.discount

          else 0.00  

            end)
```

I keep running into this error:

> Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s).

How do I fix this issue? I need the price to be calculated either when the table is created or when data is added.

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot reference fields from other tables in the expression of the calculated field, since no subqueries are allowed. So, even if we fix the syntax error for you, it would not work. This task seems to require a trigger, or stored procedure, or view.
2. Even though you can have an expression after the case keyword, listing column names is not a valid expression, since it does not return a single value.

Comment: i see. how would you make the procedure for this then

Comment: 1. This is a different question, so ask it in its own post. 2. Provide a lot more details as to what you are trying to achieve and how you have tried to solve it in the new post. Because based on just the above I cannot answer your new question even if I wanted to.